# MongoDB / MongoHQ field=>value size limit?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongohq

I'm querying my MongoDB which is hosted as a trial account over at MongoHQ for a document which has a field containing over 1000 values. When I try to retrieve this document, my query simply doesn't return anything. If I try shortening the field to say, 100 values, it works fine. I have one doc in this collection with a similar field that has 586 values and it loads as well.

I'm wondering is there some kind of limit being imposed here that I'm not aware of? There's no way the doc is over 4MB.

**UPDATE:** Realized there were some values that were evaluating to null, this was causing the query to break. Solved.

Comment: It is now **16MB**. **update to new version** Ref: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Documents

Comment: Huge nested document can exceed te document size limit. Using Db-ref instead of using huge nested document would not possibly face any size limit problem.

Comment: right, but the document size limit is not what I'm asking, I better rephrase the question...

Comment: @InspiredJW 16M is only limit for insert right? I think there is no limit for query.

Comment: As I know, there is no limit for query. Only limits on insert, update, upsert

Comment: my entire collection is only 308 KB so none of the documents could be over 4MB

Answer (score 0):

**MongoDB** Document size limit is now **16MB**. [Reference](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Documents)

Update to new version!

Huge nested document can exceed the document size limit.

Using Db-ref instead of using huge nested document would not possibly face any size limit problem.